# How to build a simple notification application as non-developer?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I want to build an iPhone app - the entire purpose of which is to send push notifications.

In this case it'd send one quote from a famous person a day. The interface would just be a preference screen where you can control what time of day you'd like the notification to be sent, so it's pretty bare bones.

I don't really have the development chops to write it from scratch so I was wondering if there's an ideal platform, app-builder, or whatever to create it with.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [www.elance.com](http://www.elance.com)

Answer (score 0):

The application itself will be easy to implement. But the other part is the Pushing application which will be sending the messages.

Check this tutorial here, [Programming Push Notification Service](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services)

Answer (score 0):

You might not necessarily need push notifications; if your quotations can be stored on the device, you can show them using local notifications instead.